# How to check if a filesystem is mounted with a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, mount

I am new at scripting ... I can do very basic stuff, but now I need a hand.

I have a local filesystem that only will be mounted when I need to do a backup.

I'm starting with this.

```
#!/bin/bash
export MOUNT=/myfilesystem

if grep -qs $MOUNT /proc/mounts; then
  echo "It's mounted."
else
  echo "It's not mounted."; then
  mount $MOUNT;
fi
```

As I said, I'm very basic at scripting. I heard that you can check the status of the `mount` command by looking at the return codes.

```
RETURN CODES
       mount has the following return codes (the bits can be ORed):
       0      success
       1      incorrect invocation or permissions
       2      system error (out of memory, cannot fork, no more loop devices)
       4      internal mount bug
       8      user interrupt
       16     problems writing or locking /etc/mtab
       32     mount failure
       64     some mount succeeded
```

I don't know how to check that. Any guidance?

Comment: You have a funny dangling `; then` in your script.

Comment: why are we exporting the MOUNT var  and also remove the  ";"

Comment: Similar questions are on [Server Fault](//serverfault.com/q/50585), [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/q/9422461) and **Unix & Linux Stack Exchange**.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can check the status code of `mount`, and most well written executables, with the shell special parameter `?`.

From `man bash`:

`?  Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.`

After you run the `mount` command, immediately executing `echo $?` will print the status code from the previous command.

```
# mount /dev/dvd1 /mnt
  mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
# echo $?
  32
```

Not all executables have well defined status codes. At a minimum, it should exit with a success (0) or failure (1) code, but that's not always the case.

To expand on (and correct) your example script, I added a nested `if` construct for clarity. It's not the only way to test the status code and perform an action, but it's the easiest to read when learning.

Note the spaces around the mount path to ensure partial paths weren't matched.

```
#!/bin/bash
mount="/myfilesystem"

if grep -qs " $mount " /proc/mounts; then
  echo "It's mounted."
else
  echo "It's not mounted."
  mount "$mount"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Mount success!"
  else
   echo "Something went wrong with the mount..."
  fi
fi
```

For more information on "Exit and Exit Status", you can refer to the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html).

Comment: There's no need to export `$MOUNT`. This script will also break if the filesystem has any character that would undergo wordsplitting (spaces, etc.). You should *always* quote your expansions.

Comment: @ChrisDown You're right. I only deleted the obvious dangling ';then'. In the future, feel free to edit my answer to make it more correct.

Comment: Er... this will still break. You have still not quoted the expansions. On your advice, I'll do it now.

Comment: I also wouldn't recommend linking to the infamous "Advanced" Bash scripting guide, it's full of errors and will teach people to write bugs, not scripts. [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is a far better alternative.

Comment: @ChrisDown "Word splitting will eat your babies if you don't quote things properly." Words to live by.

Comment: grep manpage says `-q Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found`. Shouldn't the conditions be swapped?

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933843/why-0-is-true-but-false-is-1-in-the-shell

Answer (score 54):

Many Linux distros have the `mountpoint` command. It can explicitly used to check if a directory is a mountpoint. Simple as this:

```
#!/bin/bash    
if mountpoint -q "$1"; then
    echo "$1 is a mountpoint"
else
    echo "$1 is not a mountpoint"
fi
```

Comment: This approach will fail if you try to check an encfs, since you will stumble into a permission denied error, when run by a non-root user.

Comment: My solution works with encfs.

Comment: Avoid `-q` (`--quiet`) option when trying this in the command line, it will print nothing, ofcourse.

Comment: @Danijel you don't need to "avoid" it when testing, you can just look at the exit code, which is what the code above does anyway. Something like `mountpoint -q "/tmp" ; echo $?` -- if it returns `0` it would say that it's a mount point, otherwise not. The reason this is better (in my opinion) is that it shows you the same logic that `if` will look for.

Answer (score 9):

**One more way:**

```
if findmnt ${mount_point}) >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  #Do something for positive result (exit 0)
else
  #Do something for negative result (exit 1)
fi
```

Comment: Hello @sungtm; it appears you logged in with a new, separate account. Since your ["Sun"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/291500/sun) account does not have much activity, I'll suggest that you continue using your new ["sungtm"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/291502/sungtm?tab=profile) account, as that is simpler. If, however, you'd like to merge the accounts, let me know by flagging this comment and we'll reach out to the Stack Exchange team. Thank you!

Comment: Note that for encfs, `findmnt` has to be supplied with the parameter `--source encfs`, otherwise it will always consider the directory to be mounted because it falls back to the parent mount.

Comment: Good answer ; in fact should be the correct answer. `findmnt` is eminently script-able, and according to `man mount`, "For more robust and customizable output use findmnt(8), especially in your scripts."

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way which doesn't require root is:

```
if $(df | grep -q /mnt/ramdisk); then

fi
```

or to see if it isn't mounted:

```
if ! $(df | grep -q /mnt/ramdisk); then

fi
```

Comment: the `mount` command doesn't need root access, `df` is focused on disc space not on mount points...

Comment: Um, these _sh_ snippets are just plain wrong. What's that command substitution doing in there (`$(`…`)`)?

Comment: Why would you not run it as root? It's a backup job, most likely it will require root privileges to backup everything.

Answer (score 2):

### Short [statements](https://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/10/01/replace-if-then-fi-with-and-in-bash/)

Check **if mounted**:

```
mount|grep -q "/mnt/data" && echo "/mnt/data is mounted; I can follow my job!"
```

Check **if not mounted**:

```
mount|grep -q "/mnt/data" || echo "/mnt/data is not mounted I could probably mount it!"
```

Comment: What happens if `/mnt/datastore` is mounted? Your script will incorrectly say `/mnt/data` _is_ mounted

Comment: add a space after data: ... grep -q "/mnt/data ".  It's generally better to use single quotes though as shell expansion may happen on double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have  tried with below script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the file system to check whether its mounted or not"
read p
echo $p
for i in `cat /proc/mounts`
do
if [[ $p =~ $i ]]
then
echo "$p is mounted"
else
echo "$p is not mounted"
fi
done
```

Only input you need to give is name of filesystem

Answer (score 0):

I try the following and it works.
It is basic, I hope I can help you.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /tmp/demo.txt /etc/demo.xt /var/demo.txt /var/log/demo.txt /opt/demo.txt /demo.txt
do
touch $i
if [ -f $i ];
then
rm $i
echo "FS bien! $i"
else
message="FS es R/O!"
echo '${message} $i' 
fi
done
```

Script output.

```
FS es R/O! /tmp/demo.txt
FS bien! /etc/demo.xt
FS bien! /var/demo.txt
FS bien! /var/log/demo.txt
FS bien! /opt/demo.txt
FS bien! /demo.txt
```

Comment: How does this tell you whether a specific file system is mounted?

Comment: What is done with this script is to validate that FS has been mounted as "read-only", a file is created inside the common mount points (you can add more if you need to) and on the FS that cannot write no will send the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check the return status of mount. The problem is, if the filesystem is already mounted and you try to mount it again, mount will return error 32. Strictly speaking the mount failed because it was already mounted.  To get around that, for example for a one-liner for a root cron backup job I would do this:

`mount /myfilesystem 2>/dev/null; grep -qs '/myfilesystem ' /proc/mounts && backupscript && umount /myfilesystem`

So essentially just mount the filesystem, then verify it's mounted and if so, run the backup script. Not super-elegant, but quick and dirty and gets the job done.

*Yes I know this is an ancient question, and the OP by now is probably senior sysadmin, but I had the same question and wanted to see if I could find a better solution.*